# How Can I Solve This Inequality Using Environmental Inequality?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

How can I prove this inequality?

$$\frac{(a+b)^2}{x+y} \leq \frac{a^2}{x} + \frac{b^2}{y},$$

where $a,b \geq 0$ and $x,y >0$.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Are you asking how to *prove* it, or literally how to *solve* it (isolate one of the variables)?

Comment: This is direct Cauchy-Schwarz ?

Comment: @NateEldredge how to prove

Comment: @Maria Pop I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: i think i just figured out the brackets and bring them to the same common denominator, then i can get to a perfectly larger square than the obvious zero

Comment: @MariaPop Show us what you got 

Comment: i got $0 \leq (ay-bx)^2$

Comment: It is obviously true

Comment: Maria: look up Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, in particular Titu's lemma, this helps you verbatim !

Comment: @MariaPop That is correct. Indeed $$\frac{a^2}{x}-\frac{(a+b)^2}{x+y}+\frac{b^2}{y}=\frac{(a y-b x)^2}{x y (x+y)}$$